# How do I correct the directions the motors move in corresponding to the gamepad?

Tags: java, android, math, gamepad

I'm trying to code a Tetrix robot to strafe using Android Studio. The motors are not moving accordingly. The left stick is making the robot spin if moved in any direction. The right stick when moved to the left, makes the robot move to left and when moved right, makes the robot move right. I'm having trouble understanding the math aspects of the code as well.

```
double r = Math.hypot(gamepad1.left_stick_x, gamepad1.left_stick_y);
double robotAngle = Math.atan2(gamepad1.left_stick_y, gamepad1.left_stick_x) - Math.PI / 4;
double rightX = gamepad1.right_stick_x;
final double v1 = r * Math.cos(robotAngle) + rightX;
final double v2 = r * Math.sin(robotAngle) - rightX;
final double v3 = r * Math.sin(robotAngle) + rightX;
final double v4 = r * Math.cos(robotAngle) - rightX;

leftFront.setPower(v1);
rightFront.setPower(v2);
leftRear.setPower(v3)
rightRear.setPower(v4);
```

Comment: **JAVA !== JAVASCRIPT** Javascript = cool ;)

Comment: I don't think this is going to be enough info for anyone to help you.  The control code does not seem to be here.  In addition, if you wire the motor yourself, this may not be a software problem at all...